# How to implement pagination in joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I am implementing pagination in joomla.The following is the code

```
      $db = JFactory::getDbo();
      $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                        ->select('c.*,cat.alias as catalias')
                        ->from('#__content AS c')
                        ->from('#__categories AS cat')
                        ->where('c.catid=19','AND')
                        ->where('c.state=1','AND')
                        ->where('c.catid = cat.id')
                        ->order('c.created '.' ASC');

    $db->setQuery($query,0,5);
    $results = $db->loadAssocList();
    $db->setQuery('SELECT FOUND_ROWS();');
    jimport('joomla.html.pagination');
    $pager= new JPagination($db->loadResult(), 0, 2);

    foreach ($results as $res) {  
    echo $res['id'];
    ....
    .....
    }

    echo $pager->getListFooter();
```

This shows page numbers at footer(like 1 2 3 with hyper links) based on page limit(6 records in 3 pages(page limit 2)).But all the records displayed in single page.Not like two records in each page.

what changes need here.Please help me anyone.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Joomla 2.5 pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549618/joomla-2-5-pagination)

Comment: fas M , I need it in single file(I used in template) for joomla latest version(3.3.6).In the above link they used in MVC pattern for joomla 2.5

Comment: What are you creating? Pagination doesn't go in a template in Joomla its used in components.

Comment: cppl,In template file at some position I displayed content from db.Like    "if ($this->countModules('position-1')){}" here in-between curly braces I wrote above(my question) code.For that data I need pagination.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution for my question:

```
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $limit = $app->getUserStateFromRequest("$option.limit", 'limit', 2, 'int');
    $limitstart = $app->input->get('limitstart', 0, 'INT');
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
             ->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS c.*,cat.alias as catalias')
             ->from('#__content AS c')
             ->from('#__categories AS cat')
             ->where('c.catid=19','AND')
             ->where('c.state=1','AND')
             ->where('c.catid = cat.id')
             ->order('c.created '.' ASC');

    $db->setQuery($query,$limitstart, $limit);
    $results = $db->loadAssocList();
    if(!empty($results)){
        $db->setQuery('SELECT FOUND_ROWS();');
        jimport('joomla.html.pagination');
        $pager= new JPagination($db->loadResult(), $limitstart, $limit);

        foreach ($results as $res) {  
            echo $res['id'];
            YOUR_CODE_HERE
        }

        echo $pager->getListFooter();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the default articles pagination you have to override the default template of the pagination content plugin.

Comment: Can you explain how that is done?  Otherwise it may not be of much help.

Comment: Here you may find how to override pagination files https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Pagination_Links_Overrides